# ¿Cómo extraer información de una ruta de archivo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Por ejemplo, tengo esta cadena: `\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.pdf`

Lo que quiero es extraer la extensión de ese archivo, en este caso lo que está después del último punto. Que me quede solo la extensión del archivo en una variable y el resto en otra. Y extraer lo que está después del último `\` De esta manera:

```
SET @Variable1 = '\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\'    
SET @Variable2 = '.pdf'    
SET @Variable3 = 'nombremanual'
```

Pensé en hacer una combinación de las funciones `CHARINDEX` y `SUBSTRING`, pero no sé bien cómo realizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener información de una ruta de archivo podrías considerar:

```
DECLARE @RUTA_ARCHIVO VARCHAR(100) = '\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.pdf'
DECLARE @ARCHIVO_RUTA VARCHAR(50), @ARCHIVO_NOMBRE VARCHAR(50), @ARCHIVO_EXTENSION VARCHAR(50)

SELECT
    @ARCHIVO_RUTA = LEFT(@RUTA_ARCHIVO, LEN(@RUTA_ARCHIVO) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO)) + 1),    
    @ARCHIVO_NOMBRE = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO)) + 1, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO)) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO)) - 1)),
    @ARCHIVO_EXTENSION = RIGHT(@RUTA_ARCHIVO, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@RUTA_ARCHIVO)))

SELECT 
    @ARCHIVO_RUTA [RUTA ARCHIVO],
    @ARCHIVO_NOMBRE [NOMBRE ARCHIVO], 
    @ARCHIVO_EXTENSION [EXTENSION ARCHIVO]
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +-----------------------+----------------+-------------------+
> |     RUTA ARCHIVO      | NOMBRE ARCHIVO | EXTENSION ARCHIVO |
> +-----------------------+----------------+-------------------+
> | \\127.0.0.1\Manuales\ | nombremanual   | .pdf              |
> +-----------------------+----------------+-------------------+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/GMQA31849)

Answer (score 2):

Intenta una combinación de [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql),  [REVERSE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql), [LEN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql) y [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) para poder extraer las extensiones.

Acá un demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f48d6/16/0

Suponiendo un schema como el siguiente

```
create table cadenas(
  cadena varchar(64) not null
);

insert into cadenas(cadena) values
('\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.pdf'),
('\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.rtf'),
('\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.doc');
```

Con esta consulta extaerías las extensiones

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(cadena, LEN(cadena) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(cadena)) + 2, 100) FROM cadenas;
```

Comment: Listo, el código ha sido agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Yo primero me ayudaría de la función [instr()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) para localizar la posición de la extensión,
para ello podrías hacer algo como esto;

Donde `instr(texto,textoBuscado,posInicial,posFinal)` sustituyendo;

```
instr('\\127.0.0.1\Manuales\nombremanual.pdf','pdf',1,3);
```

esto devolvería la posición donde empieza la cadena `'pdf'` dentro de la cadena madre.

Una vez tenemos la posición me ayudaría de la función substr

```
substr(texto,posInicial,posFinal);
```

Comment: eso es Oracle, no TSQL